# PHP - filter UTF-8 string to allow only basic charset and some punctuation

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii

(I don't think this is a duplicate question-- I found many questions *close* to this but could not find anything that asks exactly this.)

I have a site where users enter a member name. The entire site (PHP, database) is UTF-8, and I want to allow members to enter UTF-8 characters (emojis, etc) in other places. But for the member name, I need to limit the content to basic letters and a few punctuation characters.

What's the right way in PHP to filter a UTF-8 input string (from a ) and filter out all characters except A-Z, a-z, 0-9, "_" and "-"?

Comment: wouldn't regex do the trick? something like $clean = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $string);